# SDL Web 8.5 RTF generating <br> and <div> instead of <p> tags

Tags: cme, gui-extensions, web8.5, rtf

When author copy/paste text paragraphs using Notepad, unnecessary `<br><div>` tags displays instead of `<p>` tags in in RTF Fields.

**Firefox Version (52.2.0 Firefox Extended Support Release ESR)**

Actual results:

```
<br xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"></br> •    TEST </text>
```

Expected result:

```
 <p xmlns=”http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml”>•    TEST 2</p>
```

**Google Chrome Version 59.0.3071.104 (Official Build) (32-bit)**

Actual results:

```
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">• Google Chrome test1  </div>
```

Expected result:

```
 <p xmlns=”http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml”>•    Google Chrome test1 </p>
```

**Internet Explorer Version: 11.0.9600.18665CO**

Actual results:

```
<br xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"></br>• Internet Explorer Version
```

Expected result:

```
 <p xmlns=”http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml”>•   Internet Explorer Version1 </p>
```

Looking for solutions to resolve `<br><div>` tag issue in RTF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

br tag generating on the 1st and 2nd (or subsequent) embedded rich text field when content copy and paste. The below code event fire when click the "INSERT" button for the 2nd embedded rich text field.

```
$evt.addEventHandler(fieldBuilder, "change", _applyLoadEvent_cpc);      
$evt.addEventHandler(fieldBuilder, "insert", _applyLoadEvent_cpc);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can select the copy pasted content and change it to paragraph using the options available in Ribbon menu.

Answer (score 2):

Notepad is a plain text editor and doesn't support rich text (like paragraphs or bullets), so your expected results are sort of impossible if you ask me.

The RTF editor in the CME currently has a tight relation to the browser used, which is why you will indeed see different results depending on in which browser you paste your text. But in the end, if you are pasting from Notepad, don't expect any Rich Text features to be pasted in there, it is simply plain text what you are pasting, so there is no additional markup.

I've heard plans of wanting to replace the Rich Text editor for a better one, which should at least unify the results among different browsers, and personally I would love for it to support [Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown), since then you can use plain text markup which is a lot better visible than HTML (which will always be hidden in a source tab).